# Kendo datasource: add method wipes out existing data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

The code below gets my list of categories and displays them. However, when I uncomment the middle line of code to add an "All Categories" entry then all the other categories go away and it only displays the inserted "All Categories" entry.

```
var categoryDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: { read: resolveUrl('~/Catalog/Categories') },
});

//categoryDataSource.insert({ "Title": "All Categories", "OID": "0" }, 0);

$("#categoriesDropDown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Title",
    dataValueField: "OID",
    dataSource: categoryDataSource
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [I moved my answer to comments as it's not the problem you're facing. @Robin's answer is best.] You have your parameters backwards according to the [Kendo UI API Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-insert).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is because the dataSource hasn't done a fetch of the data, it doesn't have a set of records to insert into.  So when you insert one, it trounces all over what is going to be used as the data set.
I can reproduce the behavior using a local array (http://jsbin.com/xaruka/1/edit?html,js,output).

I think you do a read once the dataSource is setup, it will have its internal list of items to insert into.

```js
var categoryDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: { read: resolveUrl('~/Catalog/Categories') },
});

categoryDataSource.read();

categoryDataSource.insert(0, { "Title": "All Categories", "OID": "0" });

$("#categoriesDropDown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Title",
    dataValueField: "OID",
    dataSource: categoryDataSource
});
```

Working sample  http://jsbin.com/xaruka/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Alternatively, if this insert needs to be done every time the read occurs, you can put the insert code into the `requestEnd` callback event function of the data source. [Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd)